# Windows script to compare folders recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need windows batch script to compare two folders(folder A and folder B) recursively and show only files that are missing in folder A.

I tried this but it's not recursive:

```
@echo off
if "%2" == "" GOTO Usage

cd /D %1
if errorlevel 1 goto usage

for %%x in (*.*) do if NOT exist %2\%%x echo missing %2\%%x
cd /D %2
for %%x in (*.*) do if NOT exist %1\%%x echo missing %1\%%x

goto end

:usage
echo Usage %0 dir1 dir2
echo where dir1 and dir2 are full paths
:end
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Only missing files? Not changed files? Not missing folders?

Answer (score 4):

Quick way to check would be to try the following

```
Cd Folder1
dir *.* /s > Folder1.txt
cd Folder2
dir *.* /s > Folder2.txt
```

Compare both text files to see the difference in files

Answer (score 0):

You should use diff.exe :
https://code.google.com/p/unix-cmd-win32/downloads/detail?name=diff.exe&can=2&q=

Then, compare the trees :

```
@echo off
if "%1" == "" GOTO Usage
if "%2" == "" GOTO Usage
cd /D %1
if errorlevel 1 goto usage
cd /D %2
if errorlevel 1 goto usage

set TEMP1=C:\temp\dir1
set TEMP2=C:\temp\dir2

dir /s %1 > %TEMP1%
dir /s %2 > %TEMP2%
diff.exe %TEMP1% %TEMP2%

del %TEMP1% %TEMP2%

goto end

:usage
echo Usage %0 dir1 dir2
echo where dir1 and dir2 are full paths
:end
```